# Can I omit generic parameters where they are derived from another?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

Say I have something like this:

```js
type RecordsObject<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  primaryKey: K; 
  data: Array<T>; 
}
```

where the type `K` is necessarily  derived from the type `T`.

I've found I frequently run into issues where where I declare something is of this `RecordsObject` type, TypeScript insists that I define both generic parameters.

For example:

```js
type Student = {
  id: string; 
  name: string; 
}

function processStudentRecords(records: RecordsObject<Student, keyof Student> ) {
  const allPrimaryKeys = records.data.map(v => v[records.primaryKey]); 

}
```

The thing is - I shouldn't have to declare the second generic parameter here - I can't see that I'm adding any additional information here.

But if I leave it off I get:

```
function processStudentRecords(records: RecordsObject<Student> ) { //Generic type 'RecordsObject' requires 2 type argument(s).(2314)
  const allPrimaryKeys = records.data.map(v => v[records.primaryKey]); //Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
}
```

Is there some kind of syntax to say 'work this out for yourself'?

If not, is there a reason that this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [assign generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).

```
type RecordsObject<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  primaryKey: K; 
  data: Array<T>; 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwM4HkBGArBwAPACoA0UA0lBAB7AQB2GUA1hCIgGZTFQC8rdlx4A+flADeAKChQwyAJYBbAIbIQFdgC5KAbigyoqFcBU6AgsmQqQJEfqkBfKS9CQoAZWABXVI2Di0rIKqDrowIoMAOYOsgwqShBhEQrRDs5SnN4M8MAKiAxyyIjwEOjoXr7+cEho6AAUyAgoGDo1LVh4BISVfgzAYgCUkgaySAzhUCoANtMACoqq6pog6OJNtRgAdMamW6pg9QBu-GJHANobHVvyymoa7AC6g+lAA)

Comment: Hey, quick question what is the difference between.  K extends keyof T = keyof T and K =  keyof T? as it seems thats all you want to do? Plus I deleted my silly answer :-)

Comment: @Cleanbeans `K = keyof T` means that `K` can be absolutely anything, but if it isn't set it will default to `keyof T`.  `K extends keyof T = keyof T` also defaults to `keyof T` if not set, but it limits the allowed values of `K`.  `K` must be a subset of the keys of `T`: either all keys, one specific key, or a union a few keys.

Comment: @LindaPaiste appreciate the guidance. Thanks!